# Rancher v3 Api Documentation not available

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

With the release of version 2.x of rancher we started using v3 of the Apis but to my despair there is no proper documentation for the apis. 
If we visit the Rancher Documentation Page https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/api/ we just find the brief intro and not the information about how to use the specific endpoints and what are the inputs accepted by them.
For eg we have a v3/cluster endpoint to create the cluster but it requires "n" number of inputs in the form strings/objects. How could one find out what all attributes are needed and also what all attributes map to what thing in the UI.

There is some documentation available for v2 of the api but things have changed miles with the introduction of v3 of Rancherapi.

**UseCase :** I need to automate the complete process of cluster creation to helm chart installation

I took some help from the medium blog : https://medium.com/@superseb/adding-custom-nodes-to-your-kubernetes-cluster-in-rancher-2-0-tech-preview-2-89cf4f55808a  to understand the APIs

Comment: Your best bet is to look at the sample code here: https://github.com/rancher/validation/tree/master/tests/v3_api

Answer (score 2):

Quite good fragment of Rancher documentation about v3 API you can find here: 
[v3-rancher](https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/468859/Rancher%202.0%20Architecture%20-%20Doc%20v1.0.pdf) (starting from page 9).

Source code you can find here: [`rancher-v3-api`](https://github.com/rancher/validation/tree/master/tests/v3_api).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it looks like the fastest way to get around API endpoints is to capture the API calls. It's mentioned at https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.6/en/api/#capturing-rancher-api-calls.